# How to Correctly Prep for Dry or Wet Torque Specifications

Tags: torque, fastener

Kind of two questions, but simple.

If a dry torque specification is given for a fastener, what can I use to properly clean the threads before tightening to torque?

If a wet torque specification is given for a fastener, should I first clean then apply lubricant?  And is the type of lubricant important?

Answer (score 1):

If threads are dirty ,I clean them with a wire brush. Don't know what "wet" torque means, but if you lube threads it can make a large difference in axial stress produced by the same torque. "EP" lubes like graphite and moly sulfide cause the largest affect, the specifics depend on the specific thread size and type and lube.

Comment: I found another question, with an answer, that is what I'm driving at here.  https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/39922/torque-specification-thread-lubricant-best-practice-as-specified-by-manufacturer